# Can someone near my room detect ethernet or usb tethering packets

Tags: hotspot, ethernet

Can someone near me(in same room) see the packets flowing if i share my hotspot internet with usb tethering or use ethernet cable while i'm connected to internet

Comment: What constitutes *see packets flowing*? Detect that there's an ethernet connection? Count packets?

Comment: Do you mean the packets on the cable?

Answer (score 0):

Answering on the belief that you mean private data, most likely not. But they might be able to see info on unencrypted or insecure protocols if they have a listener between you and your tethered/ethernet connected device, which in the way you phrased your question, I think unlikely.